# Liferay - autologin hook/portlet doesn't logout the current user

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

It seems Liferay's autologin hook doesn't logout the current user. So I tried to do it programmatically with the following method call:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

but with no success.Does anyone had the same issues with the auto-login hook ?

Comment: You can redirect to /c/portal/logout

Comment: Where do you call `request.getSession().invalidate();`? If you call it from one of your custom portlets, you will only invalidate the session of your webapp, not the session of Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to logout you have to invalidate the cookies and then invalidate the session see the Liferay LogoutAction for more detail

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/action/LogoutAction.java

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that if a user is logged in, an autologin filter is not executed, so you can't do any logout action in it.

For my solution I created a servlet filter which check some paramteres for autologin and execute logout process. For creating a filter I follow this guide: http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2016/02/liferay-servlet-filter-hooks.html

My code for logout in **doFilter** method (in servlet filter):

```
final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

if (session != null)
{
    session.invalidate();
}

filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay 7.2, create a module portlet and do the following:

At the top after import add:

```
@Component(immediate = true, property = {"key=login.events.pre"}, service = LifecycleAction.class)
```

Customize your class as below:

```
public class LoginPreAction implements LifecycleAction
```

Add:

```
lifecycleEvent.getRequest().getSession().invalidate();
```

this will invalidate your session

Now send redirect:

```
    try {
        lifecycleEvent.getResponse().sendRedirect("/c/portal/logout");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException while redirecting::::  "+e.getStackTrace());            
    }
```